# How to get a vector from my player's origin to the wall the player collisioned with?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm making a 3d fps parkour game in Unity as a school project.

I think I got most of the parkour part working but there is one big problem left.

I wanted to give player some air movement because it is much harder to reach platforms without it, but it makes the wallrunning really hard.

After player jumps to a wall, if he/she moves even just a little bit away from the wall while he is running along it, the player breaks off of the wall and starts free falling (player can move while wallrunning because he/she is practically not on the ground so the air movement kicks in).

So I thought that creating a really strong force that pushes the player to the collisioned wall should work but when I use:

```c#
    other.transform.position-player.transform.position
```

The pushing vector I get is not the nearest point.The vector goes from my player to the center of the wall which isn't correct at all. (Since wall's center is a lot higher than player's center it creates a force that launches player upwards).

Then I tried using the `collision.contacts[0].point` but for some reason it didn't give me the results I wanted either. I am adding an image for you to see what the vectors looks like within game scene:

[image: Scene view while wallrunning]

Pink capsule is the player.Gray plane is my ground and the dark brown block is my wall.The green arrow is the vector I'm trying to find.

The blue line'code:

```c#
    Debug.DrawRay(rb.transform.position, collision.contacts[0].point, Color.blue,1,true);
```

The red line's code;

```c#
    Debug.DrawRay(rb.transform.position, collision.transform.position, Color.red,1, true);
```

Finding the vector from player to wall would also help me to implement walljump since jumping from a should create a force that pushes player away from the wall.

Comment: have you tried using the normal? https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ContactPoint-normal.html if that does not work, try this answer https://answers.unity.com/questions/279634/collisions-getting-the-normal-of-the-collision-sur.html

Comment: Using the normal solved it.Thanks.